# How do I start SQLPlus from ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlplus

I try to start sqlplus.exe from an asp page. The script that is executed does not have an exit statement, so the process never exits. Normally from a batch file I just pipe this to sqlplus and the process ends, eg.

```
echo exit | sqlplus me/me@database @c:\script.sql.
```

How do I accomplish this from ASP.NET?

Comment: Any reason why you need to start sql plus instead of using a library to connect to the database directly?

Comment: The sql scripts are generated by an automated external system. I tried using the oracle data adapter but that got stuck on all the formatting problems I ran into, like tabs, spaces, etc. It didn't seem to translate well.

Comment: @Ronald I think this is an example of an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377). You're trying some solution that isn't really appropriate instead of having originally asked about the underlying problem. George is right, you should use a library to connect to the database rather than relying on an external program. You can work through your issues with that method

Comment: If the scripts are generated by an automated external system, you have two options: Make a way to connect to that system to get the scripts, transform them to a format that works and then connect to your database through the library, or ask the external vendor to format them in such a way that they can be run with no issues.

Comment: If it helps any, it's common to have to do these sorts of things: Write wrappers for external files that allow you to work with them in a way that works for your program.  I'd personally never trust an automated external system's scripts (as you're then dealing with someone else's bugs too), so it always sounds like a good idea to have a processing step on your side to ensure their script doesn't accidentally drop the database, or truncate tables.

Comment: Yep, I understand your point. The remote system cannot be connected to, doen's serve any API's orso for that matter. It has a builder that creates sql files, and these need to be processed by my web page. So what I do now is that I copy the .sql file to something like <guid>.sql, append an exit statement and execute that one. Then remove the <guid>.sql file. That works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what I did. I copy the original file to a tempfile and paste the 'exit' statement as final line. Then I run sqlplus and the process ends fine. Nothing wrong with using the sql adapter, in fact, that should be better, but was not feasible in my case. Maybe this helps someone with the same struggle.
Cheerz!